# Content area fall of navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to making responsive website. Everything great but i have a problem. When I get smaller window, content area falls to below of navbar.

I want to stay navbar on left side and content on right side. Side by side. How can i fix that?

[image: This window]

[image: turns this]

Here's my codes

```css
 /*Navbar*/

div.navbar-inside a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "bocek-bold";
    background-color: #f1f1f1;  
    display: block;
    padding: 8.8px 14.2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #803104;;
    color: #f75c03;
}

div.navbar-inside {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table-row;       
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 144px; 
    font-family: "bocek-bold";
    font-size: 1.1em
}

div.navbar-inside a:hover {
    background-color: #db995a;
    color: #654236;
}


    /*Content*/

.content-inside { 
    font-family: "bocek-bold";
    font-size: 1.4em;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
```

```html
<!--Middle area. Navbar, content-->

  <div class="row">

    <!--Navbar-->

    <div class="col-xs-0 col-md-2 navbar-inside" style="background-color:rgb(77, 58, 95);" >
        <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 navbar-inside">
            <a href="index.html">Anasayfa</a>
            <a href="hakkimizda.html">Hakkımızda</a>
            <a href="kadromuz.html">Kadromuz</a>
            <a href="referanslar.html">Referanslar</a>
            <a href="iletisim.html">İletişim</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Content-->

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 content-inside"  style="background-color: rgb(43, 189, 226);">
        <p>
          CONTENTCONTENTCONTENTCONTENTCONTENT 
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding margin-left to your content. This way, the space inside the row (12 columns) gets 2 columns for the navbar and 10 columns+marginleft to content. As counting with the navbar, there is only room for 10 columns in the row (and not 10 + margin-left), the content won't fit there and goes down.